# Go to anchor in view, based on today's date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, anchor

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have view with sections:

```
<section id="Monday"> ... </section>
<section id="Tuesday"> ... </section>
<section id="Wednesday"> ... </section>
etc...
```

On the view there are links like `<a href="#monday">`. However, initially I would like to go to current day.

As this is MVC, I was thinking of either server-side code, that would somehow add the anchor to URL, or client-side solution, using jQuery. I already wrote code, that returns today's day, I'm only looking for a way to apply it to URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '#' + getDay()
```

Drawback: causes a page reload, or:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + getDay()).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Where `2000` is the amount of time to takes to scroll, if you don't want to scroll, you could just set this to 0. However, it won't be appended to your URL. If you'd like it to be appended to your URL use:

```
document.location = document.location + '#' + getDay()
```

Which changes the URL but doesn't cause a page refresh.

Alternatively, from the server side you could have a link using Razor

```
<a href='#@DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd")'>Today</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be some typos, but here's the idea in Razor template:

```
<a href='#@DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd")'>
```